# How to call function after sending msg to all room members?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In socket.io server side. I want to remove all users from room, after sending them a msg. But before the msg goes to all user, they are removed from room

```
socket.broadcast.to('myFavRoom').emit('good_bye_friends', {'reason':'server is loaded'});   


for (socketID in io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms['myFavRoom']) {
          if (io.sockets.connected[socketID]) {
                io.sockets.connected[socketID].leave('myFavRoom');
              }
      }
```

how can i call the loop after sending msg to all clients?

Comment: try with promise http://howtonode.org/promises

Comment: I am new to node, can you guide how to use that with socket?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the final code that worked for me. In one loop i emitted the msg and made client leave room

```
 for (socketID in io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms['myFavRoom']) {
                clientSocket = io.sockets.connected[socketID];
                if (clientSocket) {
                    clientSocket.emit('good_bye_friends', {'reason':'server is loaded'});
                    clientSocket.leave('myFavRoom');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `broadcast` and `emit` calls do not have a callback to know when they have completed, you may just need to wait. If they don't tell you when they are done, you have to guess how long it will take on your server.

something like:

`socket.broadcast.to.emit()
setTimeout( function(){
  //for loop to remove from rooms
}, 2000 );`

Answer (score -1):

Using Q library https://github.com/kriskowal/q:

NOTE: i really never used it and don't know how it works but i think it could be something like that:

```
Q.fcall(function() {
    socket.broadcast.to('myFavRoom').emit('good_bye_friends', {'reason':'server is loaded'});
})
.then(function() {
    for (socketID in io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms['myFavRoom']) {
          if (io.sockets.connected[socketID]) {
              io.sockets.connected[socketID].leave('myFavRoom');
          }
     }
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```